# Repeat jQuery ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make an ajax request to the server. And sometimes I receive 502 error. So, if that happened error() method is called.

How can I repeat request if receive an error? The code should looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'http://server/test.php',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                cache: 'false',
                timeout: 32000,
                success: function(data) {
                  //some actions here
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("Error[refresh]: " + textStatus);
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    // here I want to repeat the request like "this.repeat()"
                },
            });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can do it like this,

```
function ajaxCall(){
      $.ajax({
                url: 'http://server/test.php',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                cache: 'false',
                timeout: 32000,
                success: function(data) {
                  //some actions here
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("Error[refresh]: " + textStatus);
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    ajaxCall(); // recursion call to method.
                },
            });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Put your code in function and call this function again. like:

```
function ajaxFunction()
{
 ....
error:function(){ajaxFunction();}
}
```

Comment: From my knowledge of recursion, what would stop the function from repeating itself - e.g what would the base case be? Probably not a real comment, but thought i would ask...

Comment: @Rob - if you want to avoid a forever calling, you can count the times of calling and stop it after several times.

Comment: That makes sense - so have a variable with an initial value of 0, increment it by 1 after each call, and put the call in a while loop (which will run until the incremented value reaches a particular value).

Answer (score 4):

With calling limit, as suggested by Hadas:

```
function ajaxCall(count) {
    count = typeof count == 'undefined' ? 0 : count;
    limit = 5;
    if(count === limit) return;
    // no need to specify cache and type:
    //   type has 'GET' as default value
    //   cache has default value of false if the dataType is jsonp
    $.ajax({        
        url: 'http://server/test.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp', 
        timeout: 32000,
        async: false 
    }).done(function(data) {
        // some actions here
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        count += 1;
        console.log("Error[refresh]: " + textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR);
        // 500, 1000, 1500, 2000 etc
        setTimeout(function() {
            ajaxCall(count);
        }, 500*count);
    });
};
```

Comment: will count be a global variable here. if so, do we change 2nd line